# Not able to use struct type in Generic constraint in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I was playing with generic constraint when I found an issue. I am not able to find the answer of it except the error tip it shows at compile time.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public void Get()
    {

    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public void Get()
    {

    }
}


public class Stable<T> where T : MyStruct // NOT Allowed
{

}

public class Stable<T> where T : MyClass //Allowed
{

}

public class Stable<T> where T : struct //Allowed
{

}

public class Stable<T> where T : class //Allowed
{

}
```

Comment: `public class Stable<T> where T : MyStruct` doesnt make any sense, just use the type (no generics) and be done with it, or constrain to a struct e.g `where T : struct `

Answer (score 3):

Structs by default are sealed, so you should not use generics here.

Use:

```
public class StableStruct : Stable<MyStruct>
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafal. This is the answer. Sealed type cannot be used in struct.

Answer (score 2):

A `struct` can not inherit from an other `struct`. So in your - not working example - `T` would always have to be `MyStruct` which makes the use of generics pretty useless here.